# Using react-dnd with cytoscape.js

Tags: reactjs, cytoscape.js, react-dnd

I am trying to use react-dnd (http://react-dnd.github.io) with cytoscape.js (http://js.cytoscape.org). I would like to be able to drag nodes and edges out of the graph into React DropTargets.  The problem is that cytoscape uses canvas to draw the graph, so there are no DOM elements for react to work with.

Does anybody have an idea how to dynamically create the react-dnd DropItem when a graph node is clicked?

Comment: And the nodes properties like id and name would be the DropItems values? Can you elaborate your question a bit more (especially the react-dnd stuff what you can already provide -> Minimal Example in a snippet?)? Thanks!

Comment: Stephen T: yes, the nodes and edges come from Janusgraph/Gremlin, so they have global ids and names to identify them. I don't have an example yet, just trying to figure out if it is possible before spending time on it. From your response it sounds like it may be, so I'll try to do an example and see how far I can get, to clarify the question. Stay tuned! Thanks!

Comment: I think this may be not possible to this extent, you can always get the data out of cytoscape.js with simple click/drag/drop events provided by cytoscape, but dragging something out of the graph is not possible! If you were to add a specific node to cytoscape representing the react-dnd instance, you could wire it to add the dropped nodes directly to the outside...

Comment: What I mean is: you add a static node to cytoscape and use the cytoscape extension compound drag and drop to drop nodes(not edges unfortunately) into this node. When dropping it, you can get the data from said node and append it to the react-dnd element outside of cytoscape probably!

Comment: Yeah, that's what I was thinking: given that cyto doesn't have any DOM elements, I will need to create one just for the dnd when cyto detects a drag event on a node or edge. Currently I'm primarily interested in dragging nodes and maybe edges out of the graph, I'm not sure if I need the ability to drag things into the graph, which would be more complicated as you say. I just don't know how to do the first one, either. ;)